# Pointwise functions on vector space (reference request)

Tags: vector-spaces, continuity

I'm just looking for a reference or anything related to the question I have outlined below. I have personally never come across anything like this -

Suppose for $\mathbb{R}^n$ we define a ***continuous pointwise function*** as a function $F:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ that can be written in the form $$F(v) = (f_1(v_1), f_2(v_2), f_3(v_3),\cdots,f_n(v_n))$$

w.r.t some basis, and where the $f_i$'s are continuous functions from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Now my question is if we consider the set of functions from $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ that are generated by composing these *continuous pointwise functions*, is that set of functions equal to, or dense in set of all continuous functions from $\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$?

Note that when composing two *continuous pointwise functions*, they do not have to be pointwise w.r.t the same basis.

Comment: What is this about basis ,if looks like the $v_i $ have to be arbitrary real numbers ,to give a definition of pointwise function  so that v is an arbitrary point in $R^n$ .Your function F is called the tensor product of the functions $f_i$ .

Comment: Fair enough, you might look at these functions as functions that can be decomposed into the direct sum of real functions. (I think it’s direct sum rather than tensor product). But the question still holds @StuartMN

Comment: It's definitely not a direct sum and it is called a tensor product .

Answer (score -1):

Composing 2 of your continuous pointwise functions just gives another continuous  pointwise function . If $ F=(f_1,...,f_n) ,and G=(g_1,...g_n) then FoG=((f_1)o(g_1)...(f_n)o(g_n))$

Comment: Can you give a more detailed argument for that claim? Note that the two functions may be "pointwise" _in different bases_.

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: That definitely looks like it assumes that $F$ and $G$ are pointwise in the _same base_. The question explicitly says that is not necessarily the case.

Comment: For example, we might have $G(x,y)=(2x,y)$ and $F(x,y)=(x+y, 2y)$ (which is pointwise because $({}^1_0\,{}^1_2)$ is diagonalizable). But then $(F\circ G)(x,y)=(2x+y, 2y)$ which is _not_ pointwise -- a linear mapping is "pointwise" in the OP's sense if and only if it is diagonalizable.

Comment: If you think that F with the 2 by 2 matrix is pointwise then you have a real problem because you have not come close to giving a logical definition of 'pointwise . One problem is that this F is linear and for non linear maps what you call pointwise is called as you say called dialgonalizable   .If the map is not linear then you would need to take the differential and assume its diagonalizable in some open region but if it is only a continuous map then you have NO definition at all . Well , developing these ideas does look to me like a possible and difficult research problem ,

Comment: The OP's post contains a precise and quite unambiguous definition of what he means. The map $F(x,y)=(x+y,2y)$ is "continuous pointwise" due to the basis $((1,0),(1,1))$ with $f_1(a)=a$ and $f_2(b)=2b$: $$ F(a(1,0)+b(1,1)) = a(1,0)+2b(1,1) $$ Both $a\mapsto a$ and $b\mapsto 2b$ are continuous.

Comment: As I said in my edited post this  definitiononly works for linear maps